# Responsiveness of website not working in iphone 10 or in any iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, bootstrap-4

I am using below code for my website redirection in iframe, its responsiveness is perfectly fine in all browsers other than Safari browser in iphone mobile. i tested it in different models of iphone.

```
<head>
<title>My Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
<frame src="https://website.com/customer?id=104" frameborder="0" />
<frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

when website load in any browser it redirects website to my site and open it properly for different screens. 
but when website opens in iOS mobile phone, it is not responsive. showing weird layout of website.

---

I replaced frameset with iframe with below code, but same issue persist.

```
   <head>
   <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type='text/css'>
   body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content
        {
            position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<iframe  width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"         
src="https://website.com/customer?id=104">
</iframe>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Frameset is deprecated, you should not use it: https://caniuse.com/#search=frameset

Comment: what should i use instead of frameset?

Comment: iframe would do the job

Comment: Ok thanks, let me check it.

Comment: I replace it with iframe, but still same issue appearing. i edited the question and place the new code, please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frameset is [obsolete and deprecated](https://caniuse.com/#search=frameset), plus not supported in HTML5, probably Safari just ignore it, if you want to display another webpage inside your webpage you can use an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

You can see in w3schools example how to work with them:

```css
iframe {
  width: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  *width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

There's more info for [HTML elements - Frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames), as we read, iframe is the only valid one in HTML5 right now.

Comment: I replace it with iframe, but still same issue appearing. i edited the question and place the new code, please see.

Comment: I added some css to make it full width.

Comment: you are adding width:1px and width:100%, which should be there, both should be there.

Comment: i just checked it with this css. but issue is not resolved.